# .htaccess is not working on cpanel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Here is my `.htaccess` for `localhost:8080` which is working fine.

```
# Deny OR Allow Folder Indexes.
# Since we disable access to PHP files you 
# can leave this on without worries. 
# OR better yet, create a .htaccess file in
# the dir you want to allow browsing and
# set it to +Indexes
Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # mod_rewrite rules
    RewriteEngine on

    # The RewriteBase of the system (if you are using this sytem in a sub-folder).
     RewriteBase /rectangle/

    # If the file is NOT the index.php file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
    # Hide all PHP files so none can be accessed by HTTP
    RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ index.php/$1

    # If the file/dir is NOT real go to index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

# If Mod_ewrite is NOT installed go to index.php
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

And this is my .htaccess for `www.sunrisecoachingcenter.com` which is showing the following [**link**](http://www.sunrisecoachingcenter.com/projects)

```
# Deny OR Allow Folder Indexes.
# Since we disable access to PHP files you 
# can leave this on without worries. 
# OR better yet, create a .htaccess file in
# the dir you want to allow browsing and
# set it to +Indexes
Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # mod_rewrite rules
    RewriteEngine on

    # The RewriteBase of the system (if you are using this sytem in a sub-folder).
     RewriteBase /www.sunrisecoachingcenter.com/

    # If the file is NOT the index.php file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
    # Hide all PHP files so none can be accessed by HTTP
    RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ index.php/$1

    # If the file/dir is NOT real go to index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

# If Mod_ewrite is NOT installed go to index.php
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

What can I do now?

Comment: Try deleting RewriteBase :)

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. I got the solution just now.Needed to use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sunrisecoachingcenter\.com$ [NC]` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sunrisecoachingcenter.com/$1 [L,R=301]` but not `RewriteBase /www.sunrisecoachingcenter.com/` . Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On localhost this will work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /rectangle/
```

But whenever we are in live server we must use this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sunrisecoachingcenter\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sunrisecoachingcenter.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sunrisecoachingcenter\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sunrisecoachingcenter.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It worked for me. I think it will help the others.

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite base doesn't need your URL as I presume you are accessing it from public_html.
Change it to
    RewriteBase /

Answer (score 0):

You have error with the following line:

```
RewriteBase /www.sunrisecoachingcenter.com/
```

Try removing this as it may produce errors with your website.

`RewriteBase` is only used to fix cases where `.htaccess` is placed not at the root of a site and it guesses the wrong web path for the folder it is running in. So if you have a `.htaccess` in a folder that can be accessed at `http://example.com/sunrise/` you can use:

```
RewriteBase sunrise
```

On your localhost - it's correct.

Comment: With `RewriteBase` the rewritten URIs are *prefixed* if relative (resolved-to, not needed if within the document root). If the value given is wrong, and the rewritten URI relative (as it is), the URI has been rewritten to a non-existing URI (404).